# Cloud Composer(Airflow) to run dependent python scripts

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-cloud-composer

Python project is running multiple py scripts. Is it possible call other python scripts not from DAG but from a single python script i.e. part-of/mentioned in DAG via PythonOperator or BashOperator in Airflow.

For example I want to call other python scripts using test.py

```
curl = BashOperator(
task_id='multiplescripts',
bash_command="test.py",
dag=dag)
```

Answer (score 0):

PythonOperator is used to execute a python callable. If you want to execute a python script than just use the the proper bash command:

```
python test.py
```

so the operator would be:

```
curl = BashOperator(
    task_id='multiplescripts',
    bash_command="python test.py",
    dag=dag
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call the PythonOperator. Like that

```
def testfunction(text):
    return

test_task = PythonOperator(
                task_id="test_function",
                python_callable=testfunction,
                op_args=[ 'we are calling the function' ],
            )
```

You can see the [documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/_api/airflow/operators/python/index.html#airflow.operators.python.PythonOperator)

Comment: That is to execute a python callable. The op is asking about execute a python script